# linking mkl as lapack and blas with cmake

Tags: compilation, cmake, lapack, blas, intel-mkl

I am having trouble linking MKL math libraries to my project with CMake. The CMake config looks for LAPACK and BLAS with:

```
find_package(BLAS REQUIRED)
find_package(LAPACK REQUIRED)
```

I have a good MKL installation in my path. How do I tell CMake to use it?

I've tried various versions of this:

```
ccmake .. -DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER:PATH=ifort
    -DBLAS_LIBRARIES=path/to/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_blas95_lp64.a
    -DLAPACK_LIBRARIES=path/to/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_lapack95_lp64.a
```

but it always fails in the link step in Make with errors such as

```
undefined reference to `dgesvd_'
```

Comment: CMake _should_ pick up a properly installed MKL without issue. Are you using a new enough version of CMake? Have you set `BLA_VENDOR` before calling `find_package(BLAS)`? (See the header of your `FindBLAS.cmake`)

Comment: On the system I'm using, I needed to set these flags `-DBLAS_LIBRARIES=$BLASLIB -DLAPACK_LIBRARIES=$BLASLIB`. These flags are otherwise set by FindLAPACK/FindBLAS as pointed out in the docs: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/FindLAPACK.html. I'm still not sure why the `find_package` commands weren't finding the libraries if `$BLASLIB` is set. I will try your suggestion of setting `BLA_VENDOR`

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem when i try to compile SuiteSparse-SPQR.
The CMake can not find right BLAS/LAPACK. After a lot of invalid attempts...
I follow https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBLAS.html.

1. install MKL from its official website.
2. open CMD and run the MKL script `...MKL-Install-Directory...Intel\oneAPI\mkl\2024.0\env\vars.bat`.
3. `cmake ...your stuff... -DBLA_VENDOR=Intel10_64ilp_seq`.